# Unhide another div on image link hover

Tags: css, wordpress, html, hide, show

I've tried several remedies after searching here but can't seem to make this work.

2 separate divs: 1 div with 4 image links in separate columns (each has a CSS fade rollover effect), and one div underneath with a simple line of text in a full-width column. I'm trying to hide the text div and reveal it upon triangle image rollover.

Here's a link with the images and the first text blurb shown below: http://goodsouldesign.com/redmont

```
<div id="triangles>
  <a>image1</a>
  <a>image2</a>
  <a>image3</a>
  <a>image4</a>
</div>

<div id="blurb1>Text here</div>
<div id="blurb2>Text here</div>
<div id="blurb3>Text here</div>
<div id="blurb4>Text here</div>
```

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: jsFiddle would be appreciated

Comment: You want the words to be hidden, and then reveal on hover? Not possible - they are images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I know exactly how you have it laid out, I'm writing a new answer. While you may need the blurbs to span the full width, they are still very close to the  elements, which means they could be made into siblings. Take this for example:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <a id="tri1"></a>
  <a id="tri2"></a>
  <a id="tri3"></a>
  <a id="tri4"></a>
  <div id="blurbs">
      <div id="blurb1">Text here 1</div>
      <div id="blurb2">Text here 2</div>
      <div id="blurb3">Text here 3</div>
      <div id="blurb4">Text here 4</div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

The blurbs are now a child of the blurbs container, which in turn is a sibling of the triangles. This would allow you to use the css sibling selector `~` to access them.

Alternatively, you don't even need the blurbs container.. It might make styling a little easier, but you could accomplish this layout simply by having the blurbs be block elements, whilst the triangles are `display: inline-block;`. This would put all the triangles on the same line, and bump a blurb down below it. Give it 100% width, and it should be what you want.

Here's a fiddle that shows how to do this with no container, and the sibling selector:

```
#wrapper #tri1:hover ~ #blurb1 { display: block; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cJJtc/1/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey Blake are you available for hire for small CSS coding jobs like this one?

Comment: Sorry, I've got a pretty full workload most of the time right now.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
I realized that my answer might have been a bit to quick to dismiss what you were doing.. I assumed that you had the text blurbs in a different area than the triangles which would make this impossible... However, if the text is meant to be right underneath the images or some similar layout, you can move the blurbs to be inside of the triangles wrapper, underneath their corresponding triangle image, and then use an adjacent css selector (exactly like the example you posted in the comments) to hide and show them. Let me know if you need an example.

Pure CSS cannot be used to create an effect such as this. The reason for this is that CSS is sequential, and can only be applied in an inward and onward fashion.. Basically, a CSS selector can only apply to an element, it's siblings which come after it, or it's children. Selecting parent elements, or elements outside of an element's "family" is not something that CSS should be used for.

An effect like this would typically be done with Javascript, which has much more power of selection.

For example:

```
document.getElementById('tri1').onmouseover=function(){
   document.getElementById('blurb1').style.display = "block";
};
document.getElementById('tri1').onmouseout=function(){
   document.getElementById('blurb1').style.display = "none";
};
```

See this fiddle for a full example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/tQjd4/

(I'm not expert on javascript, so I'm sure there are more efficient ways to do it, but that works!)

I tend to use jQuery to shortcut my javascript, which would be something like:

```
$('#triangles a').hover(function(){
    $('#'+$(this).attr('rel')).css('display','block');
}, function(){
    $('#'+$(this).attr('rel')).css('display','none');
});
```

assuming that you've given each triangle a rel attr equivalent to the blurb text id

Comment: thanks for the info! I was originally trying to use this but it doesn't seem to work on my site: http://codepen.io/Pixelizm/pen/ICpKv

Comment: Yes, in the case of that example, it works because the element that is hiding/showing is a direct sibling to the hover element, which allows CSS selectors to access it.

Comment: THat makes sense Blake. Might you be able to point me to a resource that would help me use Javascript to make this happen? Thanks again!

Comment: I've added an example of how the effect might be done in javascript, as well as with jQuery. You might want to look into javascript event listeners for more information.

Comment: Thanks much! I'm giving this solution a go.

Comment: I'm not sure if you noticed the update at the top of the answer, but depending on how you want this content laid out, it might actually have been possible with css. Could you clarify the positioning of the elements that you are trying to achieve? I may have assumed incorrectly

Comment: You were right - each element is in a separate div, mainly because the image links are positioned in 4 columns and I need the blurbs to span the full width. I'm trying now to figure out how/where to include the javascript you showed. thanks!\